# ps -ef | { head -n 1 ; sort ; } Unexpected output

Tags: bash, pipe, head

Why does the following cut out the word `root` on the second line and skew the output, not to be uniform to all the following lines?

```
# ps -ef | { head -n 1 ; sort ; } | head -n11

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
      470     2  0 Oct07 ?        00:00:00 [xfsaild/nvme4n1]
apache   10210  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:04:04 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10211  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:11 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10212  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:35 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10265  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:55 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10325  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:50 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10328  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:39 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10329  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:02:59 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   10330  5801  0 Oct12 ?        00:03:50 /var/site/fastcgi.pl                                 
apache   11889  3815  0 Oct08 ?        00:33:11 /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

I'd expect output to print:

```
# ps -ef | { head -n 1 ; sort ; } | head -n2

UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       470     2  0 Oct07 ?        00:00:00 [xfsaild/nvme4n1]
```

This seems to be a Race condition. Sometimes when I run it it does not happen.

```
$ ps -ef | { head -n 1 ; sort ; } | head -n3
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
avahi       1328       1  0 Oct12 ?        00:00:08 avahi-daemon: running [danied.local]
avahi       1401    1328  0 Oct12 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
```

Comment: your question is unclear. there is no sample data. It is not reproducable.

Comment: The output of your command is not determinative, due to racing conditions about both sides requesting the pipe to close, check the example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is subject to race conditions, more specifically `head -n1` could close the pipe behind before the second command manages to get any input, if the first command also has ended.

Consider this example:

```sh
> cat test.sh
for ((i=1;i<=3; i++)); do
    printf "$i\n"
    # sleep 1
done
```

If you run this many times, you will get different results

```
> sh test.sh | { head -n1; tail -n +1; }
1
> sh test.sh | { head -n1; tail -n +1; }
1
2
3
```

If you uncomment the `sleep 1` statement into the loop, both commands will get input. Because the pipe will not be closed from the first command immediately, so the second part will wait for sure, although the first `head` is done.

Answer (score 0):

When I launch this command, this is what I get:

```
Prompt> ps -ef | { head -n 1 ; sort ; } | head -n11
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD

Prompt> uname -a
Linux ...-Microsoft #488-Microsoft Mon Sep 01 13:43:00 ... GNU/Linux
```

This makes a lot more sense: `ps -ef` shows all running processes, `head -n 1` only shows the first line, and the rest is not important.

Can you run that command again and see that everything is like you say, and run the `uname -a` command, in order to verify which type of machine you're working with? (The result of `env | grep -i "shell"` might be useful too). Just edit your question accordingly.